# DrRacket icon doesnt work?

Tags: 64-bit

I installed DrRacket from the Ubuntu Software Center.  All went well and an icon appeared however nothing happened when I clicked the icon so I removed it.

Then went to the Developer website and downloaded **full-5.3.0.21-bin-x86_64-linux-debian-squeeze.sh**.  I installed this via Terminal with `sudo apt-get install racket`. The DrRacket icon came back in Dash Home but again clicking it nothing appears to happen.

How do I start DrRacket? I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS dual boot on a 64 bit Dell

Answer (score 1):

So this is the first ever time i am giving help online to someone. i just installed it myself.
You may want to download it from their website directly at http://racket-lang.org/. Then I chose the Linux x86_64(Debian squeeze version. It has a .sh file extension. Right click on the downloaded file and go to its properties. Click the permissions tab and click allow executing file as program. then double click or right click and choose run in terminal. Follow the instructions from there to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get DrRacket working by the following steps:

1. Download the DrRacket Linux 64-bit build for Debian Squeeze at [here](http://download.racket-lang.org/racket-5-3-bin-x86_64-linux-debian-squeeze-sh.html) (**NOTE**: This URL will change when new versions of DrRacket are released; please go to http://racket-lang.org to make sure you are getting the latest version)

The file in my case was named `racket-5.3-bin-x86_64-linux-debian-squeeze.sh`

I then started the following terminal session:

```
user@computer:~$ cd Downloads
user@computer:~/Downloads$ chmod +x racket-5.3-bin-x86_64-linux-debian-squeeze.sh                
user@computer:~/Downloads$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for user:
root@computer:/home/user/Downloads# ./racket-5.3-bin-x86_64-linux-debian-squeeze.sh 
This program will extract and install Racket v5.3.

Note: the required diskspace for this installation is 285M.

Do you want a Unix-style distribution?
  In this distribution mode files go into different directories according
  to Unix conventions.  A "racket-uninstall" script will be generated
  to be used when you want to remove the installation.  If you say 'no',
  the whole Racket directory is kept in a single installation directory
  (movable and erasable), possibly with external links into it -- this is
  often more convenient, especially if you want to install multiple
  versions or keep it in your home directory.
Enter yes/no (default: no) > no

Where do you want to install the "racket" directory tree?
  1 - /usr/racket [default]
  2 - /usr/local/racket
  3 - ~/racket (/root/racket)
  4 - ./racket (here)
  Or enter a different "racket" directory to install in.
> 2

Checking the integrity of the binary archive... ok.
Unpacking into "/usr/local/racket" (Ctrl+C to abort)...
Done.

If you want to install new system links within the "bin" and
  "man" subdirectories of a common directory prefix (for example,
  "/usr/local") then enter the prefix of an existing directory
  that you want to use.  This might overwrite existing symlinks,
  but not files.
(default: skip links) > /usr
Installing links in "/usr/bin"...
  drracket, gracket, gracket-text, mred, mred-text, mzc, mzpp, mzscheme, mztext, pdf-slatex, planet, plt-games, plt-help, plt-r5rs, plt-r6rs, plt-web-server, racket, raco, scribble, setup-plt, slatex, slideshow, swindle
  done.
Installing links in "/usr/share/man/man1"...
  drracket.1, gracket.1, mred.1, mzc.1, mzscheme.1, plt-help.1, racket.1, raco.1, setup-plt.1
  done.

Installation complete.
```

Note my choices/responses to the questions that the installer asks. You might follow my example and try the same responses, but they aren't the only possible responses; you can experiment with them a bit.

Once I did that, I just ran the following command as a regular user from the `$` prompt (so, run `exit` if you're still in the root (`#`) prompt):

`drracket`

The GUI displayed.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. Not sure what problem you are having because it works for me.

Comment: Many thanks.  Had to un-install previous application.  The DrRacket GUI now appears.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer was helpful to you, please remember to **accept** the answer to reward the person who answered it with reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command in terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install racket
```

for 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

IMPORTANT: the last part for UBUNTU 12.04
After I did that, it worked. Before that, I had the same trouble.  Get both of them.